# What is the maximum size of an array field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store different kinds of list in elasticsearch such a list of friends, list of people who have liked a page etc. All these lists can run into thousands or millions.

In elasticsearch, we can store more than one element in a single field as an array. So is there any limit on the size of elements a field can store? Is this recommended?

Other way I think is that I can have a separate index to maintain this list where each item in the list will be a separate document. So that way I will have an index for storing list of users and another index to store each friend of the user as a separate document. If the user has 1000 friends then there will be 1000 documents in the second index storing user Ids of both the main user and the friend.